# Constant pointers in header files

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, header-files

I have previously encountered the following problem and have been subconsciously avoiding it ever since but have never fully understood why it is happening. Could someone explain to me what is wrong with the following?

In the header file `Library.h`

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <string>

const char ok = 'K';

const char* problem = "Problem";
const std::string fine = "Fine";

#endif
```

In the including main file `main.cpp`

```
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when compiling `multiple definition of 'problem'` even though there are guard conditions in the header file and only one occurrence of the definition of problem. This seems to apply to any pointer I place in the header file but not to normal constants such as `ok` or `fine`.

If I change problem to a non constant: `char* problem = "Problem"` I get warnings about the deprecated conversion but not multiple definitions and it compiles.

I am using g++ 4.6.3 and Code::Blocks 12.11

**Update:**
Have retested with g++ 4.7.1 (with and without Code::Blocks) and no longer get the issue. Regarding those who suggested the use of `extern` or `static` is there any other reason to use those in a case like this (where you only want a simple c-string constant) other than compataibility with older compilers?

Comment: Are you including `Library.h` from other `cpp` files other than `main.cpp`?

Comment: No this example is complete there are no other files involved. In any case changing to non const would still cause a problem then.

Comment: Something tells me, here you need `extern`

Comment: @DuncanACoulter In that case, there should not be this error, I'm sure you're missing something else. Also, it's not good practice to use constants and variables in header files.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with MSVC10 nor GCC 4.7.2. Is it maybe a problem in the compiler? Any change to upgrade?

Comment: LLVM 3.1 can't reproduce the problem either.

Comment: With the posted code, I can't reproduce this with gcc 4.6.3 - albeit running on Linux, I don't believe the compiler as such is majorly different.

Comment: `ok` and `fine` are both constant, while `problem` is not: it's a non-constant pointer to a constant char-array. To be equivalent to the other two, you'd need `const char * const problem = "Problem";`

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's particularly surprising since I was running Linux as well. I have reproduced on Windows.

Comment: @H2CO3 I can see why placing variables in header files is bad style but why would constants be?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter constants are defined and instantiated just like variables, and if once the optimizer doesn't catch a constant you can run into linker errors with equal probability. Make your constants `extern` and define them in the implementation (`.cpp`) file, or use enums or `#define` macros (depending on the use case).

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" here is that the string `"Problem"` isn't guaranteed to be the same one every time the header is included.

You could solve this by using `static`

```
static const char* problem = "Problem";
```

However, if you expect to see the SAME variable `problem` in multiple source files, that won't work either. In that case, you need to do this:

```
extern const char* problem;
```

and then in `library.cpp` or some such:

```
const char* problem = "Problem";
```

Comment: Upgarding to a newer version of the compiler fixed the issue. Would you still recommend the use of `static` and `extern`? Also regarding it being the same one each time the header is included wouldn't that be a non-issue due to the prevention of multiple inclusions?

Comment: Yes, I would. And if you use static, then you will have multiple `problem` variables that have different addresses [and the `"Problem"` string they point at may also not be the same one] - so it is not the SAME variable. That may not be an issue, it really depends on how you are using the variable.